# Magento - Get product info from cart item

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've an observer where I want to check some info from my cart items.

I want to load the product attributes for these items:

```
$items = $observer->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    if ($product->getData('my_attribute')) { 
        // My logic
    }
}
```

But my business logic is never executed as `my_attribute` is not loaded in the `$item->getProduct()` information.

I've tried to add in the `config.xml` file this code:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <my_attribute />
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>
```

The only code that works for me is loading the product individually:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

What's the difference between loading the product from `catalog\product` and the product contained in my cart items?

Comment: have you got solution from below answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this instruction:

[image]

This can be done with XML by adding the following code to your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <attribute1 />
                    <attribute2 />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

where attribute1 and attribute2 are your attribute codes. Then you can access attribute using the code below:

```
$item->getData('attribute1');
//if you use observer or quote object:
$item->getProduct()->getData('attribute1');
```

Comment: I'll try that code too, but the question, is: why `$item->getProduct()` is not loading the attributes I want even after adding them in `config.xml` ?

Comment: Check this reference : https://www.atwix.com/magento/accessing-custom-attribute-at-checkout-or-cart/

Comment: My code is exactly as the one from that page, but my new attribute is never loaded using `$item->getProduct()->getData('my_attribute')`. Only when loading  the entire product: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());`

Comment: The reason behind this is that it is unable to get the product id for whose attribute you want to see. You should always load the product using id and then you can get all the details.

Comment: If it doesn't work, this can be because your attribute is set only at store view level on product.